# Möbius transformation, determine the image area for the w-plane

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Can someone help me with this question.

Let

$D\{ z\in \mathbb{C}: Re(z)<0,|z-1|<2\}$

and look at the Möbius transformation

$f(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+1}$.

Determine the image area

$D'=\{f(z):z\in D\}$.

I have started by drawing the circle $|z-1|=2$ in the z-plane, then determine the area of the circle that fulfills the conditions $Re(z)<0, |z-1|<2$. See the figure (excuse my bad drawing).

[image]

And then I was thinking that I could choose 3 points that has this area on the left: $z_{1}=-i, z_{2}=0, z_{3}=i$ and then calculate the corresponding $w_{1}, w_{2}, w_{3}$ by using the formula above $f(z)=w$.

Then I get $w_{1}=-i+1$, $w_{2}=-i$ and $w_{3}=0$, how can I draw the image area for the w-plane from this? Do I have to do something else?

Comment: Hint: Mobius transformations take generalized circles to generalized circles.  Therefore, if you pick three points on the boundary, you can find the circle that contains their images.

Answer (score 0):

In your set-up, your region of interest is bounded by a circle and a line.  The circle has real equation:
$$
(x-1)^2+y^2=4
$$
and the line has real equation:
$$
y=0.
$$

Mobius transformations (and circle inversions, in more generality) take generalized circles to generalized circles.  The phrase generalized circles is just a name for circles and lines.

So, in your example, you've got to find the generalized circles that your objects transform into.

- For $(x-1)^2+y^2=4$, we can take the points $z=-1$, $3$, and $1+2i$.  By applying the transformation to each of these three points, we get

  1. $f(-1)=\frac{-1-i}{-1+1}=\infty$.
  2. $f(3)=\frac{3-i}{3+1}=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{4}i$
  3. $f(1+2i)=\frac{1+2i-i}{1+2i+1}=\frac{1+i}{2+2i}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Since one of the points on the boundary of the circle is taken to infinity, this circle maps to a line.  Moreover, the line passes through $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{4}i$.  This means that you're looking at the line $y=-x+\frac{1}{2}$.

- For $y=0$, three nice points are $z=0$, $z=i$, and $z=\infty$.  By applying the transformation to each of these three points, we get

  1. $f(0)=\frac{0-i}{0+1}=-i$.
  2. $f(\infty)=\frac{\infty-i}{\infty+1}=1$.
  3. $f(i)=\frac{i-i}{i-1}=0$.

Therefore, this line becomes the circle passing through $0$, $1$, and $-i$.  The center of the circle must be on the bisector of the segment between $0$ and $1$, so its real part is $\frac{1}{2}$.  Similarly, the center of the circle must be on the bisector of the segment between $0$ and $-i$, so its imaginary part is $-\frac{1}{2}i$.  Hence, the image of the line is the circle $\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{2}$.  (The $\frac{1}{2}$ on the RHS comes from recalling that $0$ is on the circle.)

So, the region of interest for you is one of the four regions determined by this line and circle.  Since the boundary of your region includes the point $-1$, which is mapped to $\infty$, this should be an unbounded region.  So, the area should be infinite.

Comment: If I choose these points I get $f(3)=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{i}{4}$, $f(-1)=\infty$ and $f(1+2i)=\frac{1}{2}$. But how can I compute the circle that contains these points if one of them is $\infty$? Could you explain number 3.

Comment: I've rewritten the answer to be much more thorough.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand how the image area should look like, what do you mean about "one of the four regions determined by this line and circle"? I thought that the image area should be a line?

Comment: The discussion above is about the boundaries of the region, so the boundaries go to circles and lines.  The area of interest, however, is *between* the lines and circles.